# How to check if the requested memory chunk can be allocated?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm working on a C++ project where I want to utilize the TLSF (Two-Level Segregated Fit) allocator for managing memory allocations. Specifically, I need to implement a method, CanAllocate, which checks if there is enough contiguous memory available for allocation.

What would be the correct way to check for enough contiguous memory in a TLSF-based memory pool?
I've gone through the TLSF code but couldn't find a method or approach that directly addresses the need for checking contiguous memory availability.
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what tlsf code do you refer to ?

Comment: here is implementation:
https://github.com/mattconte/tlsf

Comment: Tricky to do something like this in the general sense. For example, Program A makes the test and gets back a yes. An incredibly short time later, before program A can do anything other than look at the yes, Program B, or maybe even just another thread in Program A, acquires a bunch of memory and turns the yes into a lie. You're almost always better off not testing, simply attempting to acquire a resource and handling the error if it cannot be acquired.

Comment: yes, you are right! But allocations are done in one thread